# Add admob to layout

Tags: android, listview, layout, admob

How can add `admob` to layout if code use list on `activity_main` and will show multi admob in list.

how to change

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId=""
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, "
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

    <com.finder.khmer.KTextView
        android:id="@+id/kTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="10sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainlist"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    tv = (KTextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    String[] Network = new String[] { "កម្មវិធី", "Smart", "Metfone","Beeline","QB","Emergency Number"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_main, R.id.kTextView1, Network);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you are asking. But I suspect you are having problems getting the AdView to show because the ListView is consuming the entire screen. If that is problem then the fix is to change your ListView to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainlist"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <Relative layout
```

and

```
android:layout_above="@id/..." , android:layout_below="@id/..."
```

to specify where you want the add to appear , avoiding the problems generated misusing by linear layout